# Analyzing and Visualizing Similarity with Binary Data (Dimensionality Reduction)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have a dataset of users and locations they are affiliated with, binary encoded as columns.

I'd like to visualize each user on a 2-d axis based on the similar of their affiliated locations. The closer they are in the vector space, the more similar they are in terms of locations they're affiliated with.

Here is an [example of what I'd like to create.](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/t-SNE-visualization-of-interior-items-embedding-Distinctive-classes-of-objects-eg_fig1_320012843)..where each dot represents a user and they are closer or further based on their location profile.

I am trying to think through methods to collapse the location information (many dimensions) into 2 dimensions.

The ask:

**Are there any techniques that are well suited for this problem?**

A few ideas so far:

**1) PCA (or similar):** Conduct dimensionality reduction via PCA with an eye for techniques that work with binary features (looking into Kernal PCA)

**2) Neural Network Embedding:** Apply techniques similar to word embeddings to this problem. Create an embedded layer where each user is translated into a continuous vector space (which can be reduced down to 2 dimensions).

Reproducible data below. The actual dataset is ~5k users and 50 locations, but I'd like to solution to be scalable.

```
import names 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

names_list = []

for i in range(1,100):
  single_name = names.get_full_name()
  names_list.append(single_name)

df = pd.DataFrame(names_list,columns=['Names'])
df['Var1'] = np.random.randint(0,2, size=len(df))
df['Var2'] = np.random.randint(0,2, size=len(df))
df['Var100'] = np.random.randint(0,2, size=len(df))

print(df)

#sample data
Names  Var1  Var2  Var100
0    Clayton Stocks     1     1       1
1      Gary Beavers     0     0       1
2    Kristal Feagin     0     1       1
3      Crystal Barb     0     0       1
4   William Wilburn     1     0       0
..              ...   ...   ...     ...
94    Jennifer Cool     0     0       0
95   Roberta Larsen     0     0       0
96    Malcom Mosley     1     0       1
97    Hazel Wilkins     1     1       0
98  Chanell Jaremka     1     0       1
```